# CSS Stylesheet Not Linking

Tags: html, css

Problem: Stylesheet not displaying style onto page.

Checked: It is linked correctly and even shows up under sources when inspecting the page, I have tried clearing the cache to make sure that it wasn't that.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/reglog_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://t-off.tk/style/style.css">

    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <h1>This is the webpage header</h1>
    <h2>This is the page content</h2>
    <h1> This is the footer at the bottom of the page, it is under construction </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Stylesheets:

style.css:

```
<style>
  body {
      background: #2d343d;
  }
</style>
```

reglog_style.css:

```
<style>
  body {
      background: #2d343d;
  }
</style>
```

Any ideas on what is happening would be greatly appreciated, I am at a loss here. 
Thank you!

Comment: Do not put `<style>` in the CSS files. Just the styles.

Comment: Agree with @SamiKuhmonen +1. Also be aware only your style.css body class will show because it will override the class in the reglog_style.css sheet - when loading css stylesheets order matters.

Comment: @HunterTurner Nope, no sign of any error's in the Apache2 logs

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen   Yep that's what it was, seems like such a strange thing to throw everything off. Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's an error in parsing so it will break everything very easily, not strange at all

Comment: Not strange at all, it takes less than that to cause a stylesheet, or any code error, for that matter. :

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes, that is very true, not strange in that sense, more that in HTML documents you place <html> and </html> but in css documents you do not place <style> and </style>. Just a curious thing to me.

Comment: HTML is HTML, CSS is not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by @SamiKuhonen  I had to remove

`<style></style>`